# Theorem on diophantine equations in $\mathbb Z_n$ and in $\mathbb Z$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have an exercise sheet without solutions, and I'm stuck on the last question.
We consider the following diophantine equations :

$(E11)\quad :\quad x^2-5y^2=11$

and

$(E6)\quad :\quad x^2-5y^2=6$

Both equations have a solution in $\mathbb Z_5$ (they are in fact equivalent in $\mathbb Z_5$). $(E11)$ has one in $\mathbb Z$, with $x=4$ and $y=1$. $(E6)$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z$ as it can be shown not to have any in $\mathbb Z_4$.

The question is : "Conclude from a theorem about solutions of diophantine equations in $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_n$".

I can't find a theorem that seems helpful here, and I can't even see what I might want to conclude from this ? Does it point out anything worth noticing ?

Comment: It's maybe just referring to your solution for (E6), namely that it's not solvable in $\Bbb Z_4$, hence neither in $\Bbb Z$.